# Running R code In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r, t-sql, rodbc

I Have a script of R Which working on data from SQL server, But i want to work on SQL server only Because i using SQL Server as a deployment Data source for my app 
So can i using My R code in SQL server without using (odbcDriverConnect) Function ? And what about the performance? Is it will be Slower if i run this script on SQL Server? 
I Have SQL Server 2016
And this's My script in R:

```
#loading Packages 
library(RODBC)
library(plotly)
library(gplots)
library(heatmap.plus)
library(RColorBrewer)
#open SQL Connection and Run Select Query
start.time <- Sys.time()
Test <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=Fakahany;trusted_connection=true")
Orders<- sqlQuery(Test,"
SELECT
  WHWorkOrderHeaderId
, OtherLangDescription
FROM   Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails 
   INNER JOIN Warehouse.WHWorkOrderHeader AS WHH
      ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.WHWorkOrderHeaderId = WHH.ID 
  INNER JOIN Warehouse.StockItems 
     ON Warehouse.WHWorkOrderDetails.StockItemId = Warehouse.StockItems.Id 
WHERE Type = 'IO'
ORDER BY OtherLangDescription ASC")
#Creating the correlations 
Orders$OtherLangDescription <- as.factor(Orders$OtherLangDescription)
orderList <- unique(Orders$OtherLangDescription) 
ListId <- lapply(orderList, function(x) subset(Orders, OtherLangDescription == x)$WHWorkOrderHeaderId) 
Initial_Tab <- lapply(ListId, function(x) subset(Orders, WHWorkOrderHeaderId %in% x)$OtherLangDescription) 
Correlation_Tab <- mapply(function(Product, ID) table(Product)/length(ID),
                        Initial_Tab, ListId) 
colnames(Correlation_Tab) <- orderList
cor_per<- round(Correlation_Tab*100,2)
#viewing the results 
View(cor_per)
```

Comment: Have you tried googling? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-using-r-code-in-transact-sql-quickstart shows you how to use the sproc in SQL Server 2016 if you want to run embedded R code

Comment: @Anthony i already tried this way but its take a lot of time to get Sp_External and after this long time i have an Error. So i asked hear if there's another effective way.

Comment: @believer When you say "...it takes a lot of time..." what do you mean? What is the error you get?

Comment: @tarheel i Get this error after 10 sec : **Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 1
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An external script error occurred **

Comment: @Believer You mind posting the tsql/r script in the question? Might help to see what the error could be.